# $n$th root of a matrix

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, operator-algebras

The following text is written in some paper [image] 
I'd like to know how to define the map $\psi$ on the space of square (complex) matrices . As we know, for example, the square root of some real matrix is not necessary unique and if the matrix is diagonalisable (it is always diagonalisable in $\mathbb{C}$), we might right 
$$A = P^{-1}D P$$ and take the matrix 
$$B = P^{-1} E P,\quad E:= diag( \sqrt{D_{ii}})$$
to be the square  root of $A.$
Is it the general definition of $\psi$? Taking into account the principle determination of $z\mapsto z^{\frac 1n}$ on $\mathbb{C}$ with $-\pi/n< arg(z)<\pi/n$ ?

Comment: A complex matrix isn't always diagonalisable. Take $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, for instance.

Comment: Then we might use the density of diagonalisable matrices ..

Comment: Note that $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ has no square root

Comment: That is why I said that we might use density

Comment: Use $\exp(\frac{1}{n} \log(A))$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix

Comment: In the same paper, the author states that there is well known formula for $$\psi (A) = \frac{\sin(\pi/n)}{\pi}\int_0^\infty A(t+A)^{-1}t^{1/n -1} dt$$
which works equally for operators on Banach spaces (not only on matrices)
I'd be grateful for any reference for this formula